# Do I have to add a "site" field in plugin model for my django-cms multisite project?

Tags: django-cms

I a building a multi site Django CMS project, and each website has a different content for the homepage, if my homepage has a placeholder, I want the content plugins be different for each site, is this thing supported by default? I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-site content is supported by design.
Basically each page you create is bound to a site and as a result the content for each page on each site will be different.

Static placeholders on the other hand behave differently because they're not bound to pages.

Their content is **not** segmented by site unless you pass the `site` flag to the `static_placeholder` [tag](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/templatetags.html#static-placeholder).

Comment: so pages and thier content are different for each site, thanks alot